# How does this java3d code work?

Tags: java, java-3d

I'm a unsure how the arrays are being used in this program. Can anyone explain to me how the two arrays in this program are being used?

```
import javax.vecmath.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;

public class Tetrahedron extends IndexedTriangleArray {
    public Tetrahedron() {
        super(4, TriangleArray.COORDINATES | TriangleArray.NORMALS, 12);
        setCoordinate(0, new Point3f(1f, 1f, 1f));
        setCoordinate(1, new Point3f(1f, -1, -1f));
        setCoordinate(2, new Point3f(-1f, 1f, -1f));
        setCoordinate(3, new Point3f(-1f, -1f, 1f));
        int[] coords = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
        float n = (float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(3));
        setNormal(0, new Vector3f(n, n, -n));
        setNormal(1, new Vector3f(n, -n, n));
        setNormal(2, new Vector3f(-n, -n, -n));
        setNormal(3, new Vector3f(-n, n, n));
        int[] norms = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 };
        setCoordinateIndices(0, coords);
        setNormalIndices(0, norms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works by first creating an array of points along with an array of normals and then referencing them later to create the figure. The four calls to `setCoordinate()` sets the position of the each vertex.

The `int[] coords` store the positions of the vertices for the 4 triangles that make up the 4 faces (each triangle has three vertices for a total of 12 vertices). The first triangle is made up of the 0th , 1st, and 2nd vertices, the next triangle the 0th, 3rd and 1st vertex etc.

The code for the normals works in a similar fashion to that that of the vertices

Comment: Thank you. I'd vote you up but I don't have enough rep points.